# Calling phone number from HTML5 android

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-webview

I built an android app with HTML5 and Javascript. I want to enable users to dial numbers but it is not working:
a href="tel:+201224001111">+201224001111/a>

I also added this line to android manifest xml:
    uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" /

Answer (score 2):

Daina, as I understand you're loading html5 into webview, right? In this case you need to set WebViewClient and override shouldOverrideUrlLoading method like:

```
 public static final String TEL_TYPE = "tel:";

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.contains(AppConstants.TEL_TYPE)) {
                try {
                    activity.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url)));
                    return true;
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    //you can show toast here
                    return true;
                }
            } 
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I created html files and uploaded them to monaca io website to compile them. I don't know android code.

Comment: If you want correct handling of your html5 app inside native Android app, you need to update it too. As you mentioned that you modified Android manifest file, you have it (native app). Now you need to find where html5 is being loaded and update webview properly.

Comment: I added these lines to the config.xml and it worked fine
     <access origin="tel:*" launch-external="true" />
     <allow-intent href="tel:*" />

Answer (score 0):

Compare yours with

```
<a href="tel:+15555555555">Call me at +1 (555) 555-5555 </a>
```

See https://mobiforge.com/design-development/mobile-friendliness-101-adding-click-to-call-links-to-a-website

This should work as click-to-call.

Comment: I want to to use HTML link

Comment: after I create APK file and install it on my phone, or nay phone. I t does not dial the number

Comment: Phone browsers won't directly dial the phone. They'll hand the phone number over to the app, but they won't initiate an outgoing call.

Comment: I wrote it just like you did here.If the application will not dial the number what would happen then?

Comment: @DainaHodges your <> werent closed properly

Comment: I wrote it exactly as you did here, but the link did not call the number.

Comment: @Pointy you mean I cannot call a number from  my application?

Comment: @DainaHodges in any phone browser I've ever used, I've only been able to click through a `tel:` link and get the phone-dialing app to show up, ready to dial the number. I have to click on something to complete the dialing process.

Comment: @Pointy Ok but the phone-dialing does not show up, I don't know why?

Answer (score 0):

a better approach for HTML is:

```
<a href="tel://+15555555555">call test </a>
```

and also notice that there is no need for permissions in this method.
if you like to use internal function for call in android , you can run intents for call via :

```
String phnumber =  "+155555555";
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phnumber));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

which needs call permission.
also this method below do not need permissions:

```
String phnumber =  "+155555555";
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phnumber));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

this will show the user dial pad and call button.
hope this will help!